# opengles: how to copy existing fbo's colorattachment(renderbuffer) to another fbo's colorattachment(texture2D)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, framebuffer

Platform is iPhone OpenGL ES 2.0

the framework already create an main `fbo` with renderbuffer as it's colorattachment.

And I have my own `fbo` with `texture2D` as colorattachment.
I want to copy main `fbo`'s content to my `fbo`.
I tried common `glCopyTexImage2D` way, but it's too slow on my device(iPad1).
So I wonder if a faster solution is out there.

If main fbo uses `texture2D` as colorattachment, I know just draw fullscreen quad using that texture to my fbo, but how to draw it's renderbuffer to my fbo? google quite a while but no specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

RenderBuffers are almost useless on most embedded systems.  All you can do with them is read from them with glReadPixels(), which is too slow.

You should use a Texture attachment, as you said, then render with that texture.  This artcile will help:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Render_to_Texture_with_OpenGL_ES

Comment: Since the iPad uses a Tile-Based Deferred Rendering GPU (PowerVR SGX ...), this is probably the best approach. Let it tile everything up for you and do the texture fetch in deferred tiles instead of a single memory copy operation. Reading from the framebuffer requires all deferred commands to be flushed first, whereas if you can defer this into a tile-friendly approach you will probably get better throughput. This is explained here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/OpenGLES/Conceptual/OpenGLESHardwarePlatformGuide_iOS/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html

Comment: @ClayMontgomery the main renderbuffer is created by another framework(cocos2d-x's EGLView) which I shouldn't modify its process. I just wonder if there's a way like desktop opengl's glBlitFrameBuffer funciton

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman as I said above I can't change the existing renderBuffer approach, but I'll check the article to get some idea, tks anyway

Comment: There is absolutely no reason you cannot draw into the main framebuffer using a textured quad.